# method to generate list of numbers returns empty array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

Just beginning to play with Java and not sure how to search this problem:
I want to generate an array of numbers in the given range with a method **getNumbersInRange**,

but when I call this method and pass the arguments, it returns empty array:

```
public class Bonus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printDatesBetween(2018, 2015);
    }
    
    public static void printDatesBetween(int fromYear, int toYear){
         System.out.print(getNumbersInRange(fromYear, toYear));
    }
    
    public static List<Integer> getNumbersInRange(int start, int end) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            result.add(i);
        }
        return result;
    }   
}
```

Comment: 2018 is bigger than 2015. Your loop does nothing.

Comment: Your starting year is greater than your final year, and therefore the for loop in `getNumbersInRange()` never adds anything to the list.

Comment: Hint: you can debug such problems yourself! Simply add print statements!

Comment: oh geez, ok thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing values in descending order and creating loop.
you should do something like this.

```
public class Bonus {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printDatesBetween(2015, 2018);
}

public static void printDatesBetween(int fromYear, int toYear){
     System.out.print(getNumbersInRange(fromYear, toYear));
}

public static List<Integer> getNumbersInRange(int start, int end) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        result.add(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

}